# How can I get the view object from resource ID in appium?

Tags: android, appium, android-bitmap

I am using appium for the testing automation. I need the view object to store into bitmap the current app screen.

```
public Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
    view.buildDrawingCache();

    if(view.getDrawingCache() == null) return null;

    Bitmap snapshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    view.destroyDrawingCache();

    return snapshot;
}

AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(""),capabilities);//capabilities and URL are set
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.app:id/video_view"));

View view = ?? //get view object from el
takeScreenShot(view);
```

Comment: do you want to get the `android.view.View` for the `WebElement el`?

Comment: yes, that's what I want

Comment: whats your base purpose and why do you need the `View` type of an element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should return something like `android.widget.RelativeLayout`
 (just an example) :

```
View view = el.getAttribute("className"); //get class value of the element
```

Comment: I get only `findelements()` methods for `el` object

Comment: @Gsquare : i think you're trying against the `driver` and the method is defined for the `WebElement`

Comment: Yes, you're right. But `e1.getAttribute("className")` returns string. How do I assign it to a `View` object?

Comment: @Gsquare of-course the return type of the method is a string itself. You can manipulate the string accordingly in your code to define the `view` argument you are passing to the method